Inverted animation with CSS and JS
I have created a FAB with this code.


let fab = document.querySelector('.fab');
let container = document.querySelector('.fab-container');
let fabItems = document.querySelectorAll('.fab-list-item');

fab.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  fab.classList.toggle('is-active');
  e.stopPropagation();

  if (fab.classList.contains('is-active')) {
    fabItems.forEach(function(item, index) {
      let delay = index * 0.05 + 0.1;
      item.style.animation = 'fadeIn 0.25s ease-out ' + delay + 's forwards, moveUp 0.25s ease-out ' + delay + 's forwards';
    });
    container.style.display = 'block'
  } else {
    fabItems.forEach(function(item) {
      item.style.animation = '';
    });
    container.style.display = 'none'
  }
});

container.addEventListener('click', function() {
  fab.classList.remove('is-active');
  fabItems.forEach(function(item) {
    item.style.animation = '';
  });
  container.style.display = 'none'
});
.fab-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: none;
}

.fab {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.fab-list {
  margin: 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 6px;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5rem;
  right: 1rem;
}

.fab-list-item {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  background-color: #0A9928;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveUp {
  0% {}
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -5rem, 0);
  }
}

.fab-list-item-label {
  position: absolute;
  right: 110%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  opacity: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  align-self: center;
}

.fab-list-item-label::selection {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.fab.is-active .fab-list-item:hover {
  background: #2189CE;
}

@media (min-width: 32rem) {
  .fab-list-item-label {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.fab-button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5rem;
  right: 1rem;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #2189CE;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.fab-button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.fab.is-active .fab-button {
  background: #D4421E;
}

.fab.is-active .fab-button:hover {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.fab-list-item:hover .fab-list-item-label {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fab-button-icon {
  transition: all .5s;
}

.fab-button-icon-plus {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0);
  -o-transform: rotate(0);
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.fab.is-active .fab-button-icon-plus {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}
<div class="fab-container"></div>
<div class="fab">
  <ul class="fab-list">
    <li class="fab-list-item">
      <div class="fab-list-item-label">Milestone Goal</div>
      <iconify-icon class="text-white" icon="line-md:alert" width="26"></iconify-icon>
    </li>
    <li class="fab-list-item">
      <div class="fab-list-item-label">Metric Goal</div>
      <iconify-icon class="text-white" icon="material-symbols:settings" width="26"></iconify-icon>
    </li>
    <li class="fab-list-item">
      <div class="fab-list-item-label">Goal Board</div>
      <iconify-icon class="text-white" icon="file-icons:dashboard" width="26"></iconify-icon>
    </li>
    <li class="fab-list-item">
      <div class="fab-list-item-label">Goal Board</div>
      <iconify-icon class="text-white" icon="grommet-icons:test" width="26"></iconify-icon>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="fab-button">
    <iconify-icon class="fab-button-icon fab-button-icon-plus text-white" icon="typcn:plus" width="24"></iconify-icon>
  </div>
</div>



Someone what to help me to make a correct "fadeout\close menu" animation? I have try different way but i have make wrong positions of the element on the close.
I think the problem is both css and javascript, since is not a problem of create a fadeout css, but the element position is inverted since when is open
Thanks

Please describe in details, what you want your code to do, and what it does instead. We don't know what possibly is "correct".

The fab has an fade in animation when the menu open, the element "appears". I want to do the same thing for the menu when is close, so a "fade out" animation.

Resolved in this way:
fabItems.forEach(function(item, index) {
    let delay = (fabItems.length - index) * 0.05;
    item.style.animation = 'fadeOut 0.25s ease-out ' + delay + 's forwards, moveDown 0.25s ease-out ' + delay + 's forwards';
});

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
    0% { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveDown {
    0% { transform: translate3d(0,-5rem,0); }
    100% { }
}

